# Terminator 2- What happened to the SWAT officer?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, continuity, terminator-2-judgment-day

Very minor and nitpicky question here folks, but during the hallway scene when the T800 disables the SWAT officers, I noticed that the officer to the far left is the only one who isn't seen getting shot, however, just as the T800 shoots the first guy, we see this guy on the floor for about a single frame. It just bugs me because is it a continuity error, or is it me being stupid? It's something that is so minimal that it just bugs me. Any explanation at all folks?

[image]

Comment: Maybe he spontaneously remembered reading news stories from 10-ish years ago about a dude matching this guy's description who [shot up a whole police precinct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFxaCa-hr8o) for little discernable reason, and subsequently fainted.

Comment: Possibly, although I can't imagine a SWAT officer being scared by such matters. ;)

Comment: Looking at it from the backside in slow mo it appears you are correct about a simple continuity error. I am sure they had to shoot that scene a couple of times. Even the pistol shot editing is off. No way to know unless you get original footage.